# Mock a function from the same class bring tested in flutter

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-test

I have **classA** that contain two function **functionA** and **functionB**

```
class ClassA{
  void functionA(){
    ...
    var result = fucntionB()
    ...
  }

  T functionB(){}
}
```

so I want to do unit test on the two function 
the function B is easy to test, but the functionA I have to mock functionB but the spy features in mockito (flutter) is decprecated
so how we can mock the functionB to test the functionA

Comment: Mockito has the when() function. Maybe try `when(functionB()).thenReturn(yourFakeReturn);`

Comment: well the problem that i have to use a real instance to test the function so if i create a mock so we will have a real instance and mock instance of the class and they are 2 different thing so the mockito will not work

Comment: Can you show some more code about the function and the real instance you want to Mock?